Why and under what conditions does a neon indicator light glow in an electric field?
I have a question about the ionization of low pressure neon (inside an indicator light) when put in an oscillating electric field, such as that near a Tesla coil. From reading online about the topic, I think that the field accelerates the very few free electrons already present in the gas, causing them to knock into neutral atoms, ionizing them, creating more free electrons, ionizing more atoms, and so on (if I am wrong, please correct me). When I hold a neon indicator light near a small Tesla coil by the wires, the bulb glows brighter than if I placed it on a non-conductive object which was brought near the coil (thus isolating myself electrically from the bulb). I assume that my capacitance to ground must come into play at some point, but how would it affect the accelerating of free electrons in the gas? To investigate that further I built a small flyback driver outputting approximately 3-5kV peak-to-peak, operating at 100kHz. I connected the output to two metal strips laying flat and parallel to each other held together and insulated with tape, with a sheet of 1mm plastic on top for safety. I put a neon bulb on the strips and it glowed, but after touching the bulb it actually glowed less brightly. Why is that? And on a side note, what is the optimal frequency for ionizing such bulbs wirelessly?

Consider the electric field around the coil:

Equipotential lines in green (crudely).  With the neon lamp held somewhere in that field, and ignoring the effect of a dielectric object holding them (maybe you've skewered it into something low-K like foam), we have field lines up close something like this:

Depending on orientation, the leads themselves can pick up some voltage from the field, and thus cause breakdown of the device.
How breakdown happens exactly, isn't very important, but yes, free charge carriers are part of it; we can assume enough to cause ignition at modest voltages (say, 100-200V across the bulb), and the field is present for long enough to have a very high chance of such carriers being present.  (Actual sources can be ambient UV, radioisotopes in materials of the lamp, or cosmic rays.)
Note that the lines curve more tightly around metal parts, as (ignoring inductance / electrodynamics, sticking to electrostatics here) metal drops no E field by nature, so the field lines bunch up around it.  Diagrams can be found in textbooks; and, see this for example:
 
Fig. 2.6; Design, Fabrication, and Characterization of Carbon Nanotube Field Emission Devices for Advanced Applications - Scientific Figure on ResearchGate. Available from: https://www.researchgate.net/figure/a-schematic-showing-the-spatial-distribution-of-an-electric-field-potential-around-a_fig6_312664731 [accessed 29 Oct 2024]
In this case, they're using the pointy structure to cause breakdown (field emission), but the same happens for the electrodes in the lamp.
With the leads aligned parallel to the ambient field, the voltage drop between them can be nulled out, but breakdown still occurs; in this case, the leads aren't acting as antenna, but the fact that the field is pinched near the tips of the electrodes still acts to cause breakdown, resulting in glow.
With one or another lead connected to something larger (like metal pliers, or human fingers), the amount of electric field occupied by (or more importantly, displaced by) those objects, becomes larger, and thus the voltage drop.  Consider:

Now field lines go something like in yellow, with much more voltage dropped across the gas inside the bulb near the tips of the electrodes.
As for your other situation, I don't understand; a diagram may help.  It may be that touching the bulb brought it closer to one or the other plate's potential, reducing the field across it.  Pay attention to where the ground return is, which, if not wired specifically, may manifest through capacitance in the transformer, etc.  Your body has ballpark 100s pF to the surroundings, so has a Thevenin equivalent of whatever voltage that corresponds to, and impedance of that capacitance (plus some skin resistance) at the frequency of interest.
Regarding frequency, it isn't very important, as breakdown occurs anywhere from DC to light (literally, you can excite neon with lasers if you're fancy enough).  Power delivered by the electric field is proportional to the charge delivered, which rewards higher frequencies for a given dimension of object (to a point, depending on that earlier assumption: eventually, objects become antennas, and resonance matters).  That is, to the extent you're making a capacitive divider circuit, its impedance is lower at higher frequency and thus the available power at given voltage (electric field * distance).
In the 10s of MHz range or so, and beyond, it's feasible to develop enough voltage across a single turn, or in space itself, to cause breakdown; thus there are many applications in the ISM (industrial, scientific, medical) bands, 13.56MHz, 27.12MHz, etc., where for example, electrodeless plasma discharge lamps are possible.  This extends into the microwave range, such as the sulfur lamp -- or variously questionable demonstrations using a microwave oven :).  At that point, the equivalent circuit looks less like a capacitor divider or transformer, and more just some impedance matching circuit between an amplifier or oscillator, and the equivalent resistance of the plasma.
The remaining frequency-dependent effect is deionization time of the neon gas itself; this is in the 10s of μs.  But this only determines how easily the plasma re-ignites when field reverses, and we've already assumed enough voltage (or presence of charge carriers) to do that, so it's not a big deal.  Put another way, this basically means the plasma looks resistive above 100kHz or so.  (Deionization times vary with pressure and gas, with hydrogen being the fastest (e.g. hydrogen or deuterium thyratron for fast pulsed switching), and xenon and mercury being quite slow (~ms), suitable for switching mains frequency -- hence their use in thyratrons and gas rectifiers.)
